# Determining the type of defective part on the PCB

Tags: power-supply, pcb, integrated-circuit, identification

I have a monitor that won't turn on. I opened it and found a burnt part on the board, but I can't identify that part. I want to know what this part is and what it does.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single gate pin, large copper planes as heatsink connected to multiple pins...
That looks like a mosfet or transistor.

Based on the similar wired part nearby they drive the transformer using a half-bridge.

One of them will be an N-channel and the other a P-channel. If you know more about the driving circuitry and the voltages and currents involved you could replace them. Assuming drive circuitry is still intact.